# Import and use jellyjs plugin parcel

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, parcel

I'm using [parcel](https://parceljs.org) and came across using [Jelly.js](https://github.com/lmgonzalves/jelly) and tried to import as instructed

```
import $ from "jquery";
import 'jquery-scrollify';
import { Jelly } from 'jelly.js';

$(function(){
    var options = {
        paths: '#circle-path',     // Shape we want to draw
        pointsNumber: 25,            // Number of points
        maxDistance: 4,             // Max distance among points
        color: '#ff0019',
        opacity: 0.27,
        // centroid: '.centroid-text'   // Element to move accordingly with the centroid of the shape
        // debug: true               // Uncomment this to see the points
    };

    /* Initializing jelly */

    var jelly = new Jelly('.jelly-canvas', options);
});
```

but it throws me this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Jelly is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it is because simply the element `.jelly-canvas` does not exist and

```
import { Jelly } from 'jelly.js';
```

should be

```
import Jelly from 'jelly.js';
```